# Writing a migration for a HABTM relation with supplied class names and a belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a relational model between users and courses ("courses" as in "I'm taking a course in statistics"). A class has one teacher (a User) and many students (also Users); a user can teach many classes but also be enrolled in many classes.

I believe the correct way to set up this relationship in my models would be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taught_courses, class_name: "Course"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :enrolled_courses, class_name: "Course"
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"
  has_and_belongs_to_many :students, class_name: "User"
end
```

But I have no idea how to set this up in my database (I'm new at this).

*Edit:*

I have a migration that amounts to this:

```
def change
  create_table :courses_users do |t|
    t.belongs_to :course
    t.belongs_to :user
  end

  create_table :courses do |t|
    t.string :name
    t.integer :teacher_id

    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

But when I try to create a new a user in the console, I get an error about `user_id`:

```
irb(main):007:0> u.taught_courses.create(name: "Foo bar")
   (0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: user_id
```

Where should this `user_id` be? Or should I be more specific about my foreign keys?

*Edit 2*

It turns out I also had to specify `foreign_key: "teacher_id"` on the `has_many` relation between Users and Courses for it to work.

Sorry for the misleading question.

Comment: What tutorial and/or references are you following?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin none, really; I've been trying to use the RailsGuides, but their example for habtm didn't seem to work for my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relational model seems reasonable to me. Database setup is discussed in 3.3.2 of http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema. If there's a particular portion of that section that you find confusing, it would help you asked a more narrow question.

For example, the above section includes the following sample migration. You could explain how this example does not seem to apply to your case.

```
class CreateAssembliesPartsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assemblies_parts, id: false do |t|
      t.integer :assembly_id
      t.integer :part_id
    end
  end
end
```

The significance of the `id: false` clause is explained in the last paragraph of the aforementioned section, as follows:

> We pass `id: false` to create_table because that table does not
>   represent a model. That's required for the association to work
>   properly. If you observe any strange behavior in a
>   `has_and_belongs_to_many association` like mangled models IDs, or
>   exceptions about conflicting IDs, chances are you forgot that bit.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "id: false"? The the [guide for AR associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) doesn't use this in the example migration.

Comment: Actually, that's exactly where I copied the migration from. See the link in my answer for a reference to it and see the answer update for an explanation of the purpose of `id: false`.

Comment: @ucarion so in other words what Peter is trying to say is that from this example `CreateAssembliesPartsJoinTable` is considered to be a resolving table to resolve the many-to-many cardinality that you have going on. As in database design this is not good. CreateAssembliesPartsJoinTable does **NOT** represent a model. It acts as a migration to resolve the many-to-many simply

Comment: OK, I see what `id: false` does. I would have missed that. Thanks!